# Inflate() returning z_need_dict

Tags: zlib

i m using java zlib package for extracting txt from a pdf file. But when i input first compressed stream found in this file to inflate(), it returns z_need_dict error. On getting this error i tried giving an arbitrary dictionary array to set_inflate_dictionary() followed by another inflate() call but same error appears "dictionary needed".I hv found in zlib manual that decompression application should provide the same dictionary that was used for compressing data. How can one know exactly what dictionary bytes were used while formulating this pdf file by the author? Or can one extract the same dictionary from pdf file?

Answer (score 0):

You did not correctly locate or extract the zlib stream. PDF does not use zlib streams that require dictionaries.